# How do I create a panels variant of a node view for innaccessible content?

Tags: panels

I want to over-ride the access denied error message when viewing a node that the user doesn't have access to.

I'm using the content_access module and panels.

Page manager node_view (Panels - node template)

```
Variant =>
 Selection rules =>
 Node: type Node being viewed is type "[content type]"
 Node: accessible Logged in user can view Node being viewed.
```

This works fine, but works the same without the Node: accessible

I create another variant, using a negation argument, everything the same except for the selection rules:

```
Selection rules =>
  Node: type Node being viewed is type "[content type]"
  Node: accessible NOT (Logged in user can view Node being viewed.)
```

The behaviour I expect is that, when a Logged in user attempts to view a node of this content type, the default "Access denied" message will be over-ridden and the panel variant will be displayed. However, the Access denied page is still being displayed.

Is there a way to over-ride the Access denied message with a panel variant? If so, how do I do it?

Comment: This is a similar question - trying to solve the same problem.
http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/161472/pass-node-id-to-custom-access-denied-panel-page-and-or-view-pane

Comment: I've come up with a solution, if you need it, its on the question posted above.